# How to disable the page when onload with opacity in GWT

Tags: gwt-2.5

I have a requirement where when page is loading, i need to disable (All widgets in it should be visible but disabled) the page with faded(opacity) and enable only busy indicator . .

How can i achive that in gwt? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying the following css style, masking is applied in all the browsers.
    .maskingStyle {
    background: #666666;
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    height:0; 
    z-index:10000; 
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
        opacity: 0.2;
        filter: literal("alpha(opacity = 20)");
        -webkit-transition: opacity OPACITY_DURATION;
        -moz-transition: opacity OPACITY_DURATION;
        -o-transition: opacity OPACITY_DURATION;
        transition: opacity OPACITY_DURATION;
     }

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called **masking**. There are many ways to do it. One of the way is to disable all the events by making all the widgets in the screen **readonly** and setting the opacity through css. Another way is use a transparent slight opaque image as a background with very high **z-index** property and remove that image when you no longer require it